# Difference between execute_async() and execute_concurrent()

Tags: python, cassandra

I want to know the difference between `execute_async()` and `execute_concurrent()` in python for Cassandra queries.

Answer (score 8):

`execute()` will run one statement as a blocking call that will not return until the statement is finished executing.

`execute_async()` will submit one statement as an asynchronous call that will return immediately with a `response_future` object you can use to retrieve the results with at a later time.  By calling `execute_async`, your program can continue without waiting for the statement to finish.  Since it is non-blocking, you can submit many statements by calling this repeatedly and have them be "in flight" at the same time.

`execute_concurrent()` is a blocking call that will run a list of statements in parallel and return a list of the results.  Like a thread pool, you can specify how many statements you want to allow it to run at a time.  And you can set a flag if you want it to return immediately if any of the statements results in an error.

Comment: OK. But can you tell me if execute_concurrent() starts a new thread for each statement or not?

Comment: From a quick glance at the source code, execute_concurrent() appears to be implemented using execute_async, so it likely only uses one thread.  It will create a future object for each async call, and then set a callback on each future to collect the results from each statement as it finishes.